# Converting Byte to Megabyte in Java getting zero

Tags: java

I was having some problem when trying to convert bytes to megabyte in Java. What I have tried to do is:

```
        long inodeSpace = 100000;
        long MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;
        long inodeSpaceInMb = inodeSpace / MEGABYTE;
        System.out.println("INODE SPACE " + inodeSpace);
        System.out.println("INODE MB " + inodeSpaceInMb);
```

I tried to print out the inodeSpaceMb, however, I am getting 0. Any ideas why is it so?

Comment: 100000 (inodeSpace)/ 1048576(MEGABYTE ) = 0. Seem it's a correct to me

Comment: You are doing integer division, any result less than zero will become zero. Use double instead.

Comment: @RickyMo That's not entirely true. Results can be less than zero, but any value will have its mantissa truncated, i.e. `0.73351` becomes `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast one of the two into a `double` and store the result in a `double`. Like:

```
double inodeSpaceInMb = (double) inodeSpace / MEGABYTE;
```

Comment: I see I see thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you also want some precision to a specific decimal place when you do the conversion then you can do this:

```
 public double bytesToMegabytes(long byteValue, int precision) {
     if (precision < 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Precision can not be less than 0!");
     }
     double mbValue = byteValue * 0.000001;
     BigDecimal bigDec = new BigDecimal(mbValue);
     bigDec = bigDec.setScale(precision, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
     return bigDec.doubleValue();
}
```